# Hw to remove default domain axis in combined plot

Tags: java, jfreechart, axis

I create a chart using JFreeChart. I set my domain axis to be symbolic axis, but I still see number in addition to the symbols in the x axis. Can someone help me to remove the redundant numbers in the x axis? x axis problem:

[image: x axis problem]

> I use this code. Instead of having only the symbols, I get also numbers.

```
SymbolAxis xAxis = new SymbolAxis("label", labels);
subplot.setDomainAxis(xAxis);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: I use :
SymbolAxis xAxis = new SymbolAxis("label", labels);
subplot.setDomainAxis(xAxis)
Instead of having only the symbol, I get also numbers

Comment: Have you tried invoking `setDomainAxis()` on the main plot or the other subplots?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!
I did it on the subplot.
Doing it on the main plot fixed it.
I was working on it a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped; please check the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

> I use this code. Instead of having only the symbols, I get also numbers.

```
SymbolAxis xAxis = new SymbolAxis("label", labels);
subplot.setDomainAxis(xAxis);
```

It looks like you may be using a [`CombinedDomainCategoryPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CombinedDomainCategoryPlot.html). Verify that you invoke `setDomainAxis()` on the main plot, rather than setting it on an individual subplot.